# How to convert toml-rs Map to std::collections::HashMap [Rust]

Tags: rust, hashmap, toml

I have the following `toml::map::Map` object named `groups`. How can I convert `groups` to a standard `std::collections::HashMap`? In other words, I would like to cast `toml::map::Map` to `std::collections::HashMap`.

As an added constraint, assume that the keys and values are mutable. This means that the keys may not always be "band" and "mode".

```rust
use serde::*;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use toml::value::Value;
use toml::map::Map;

fn main() {
    let v1 =  Value::String("20m".to_string());
    let v2 =  Value::String("40m".to_string());
    let v3 =  Value::String("cw".to_string());
    let v4 =  Value::String("ssb".to_string());

    let band = Value::Array(vec![v1, v2]);
    let mode = Value::Array(vec![v3, v4]);

    let mut g = Map::new();
    g.insert("band".to_string(), band);
    g.insert("mode".to_string(), mode);
    let groups = Some(g);
    dbg!("{:#?}", groups);
}
```

Comment: `map.into_iter().collect::<HashMap<_, _>>()` should do it.

Comment: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c0cd20aa521e054a2da634bbf8541180)

Comment: `HashMap::from_iter(map)`.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap::deserialize()` can accept a `toml::Value::Table`. To modify the script above try this:

```rust
use serde::*;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use toml::value::Value;
use toml::map::Map;

fn main() {
    let v1 =  Value::String("20m".to_string());
    let v2 =  Value::String("40m".to_string());
    let v3 =  Value::String("cw".to_string());
    let v4 =  Value::String("ssb".to_string());

    let band = Value::Array(vec![v1, v2]);
    let mode = Value::Array(vec![v3, v4]);

    let mut g = Map::new();
    g.insert("band".to_string(), band);
    g.insert("mode".to_string(), mode);
    let res: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = HashMap::deserialize(toml::Value::Table(g)).unwrap();
    dbg!(res);
}
```

[Rust Playground Run](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2a771a09853702171edeefe401cf314a)

Comment: Which leaves the question of why you'd get yourself into that situation in the first place? Why create a toml Map if what you want is a hashmap?